# Wireless clients disconnected from router when PS4 traffic begins

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, dhcp

I consider myself pretty good at networking, but this one has me stumped.

My brother-in-law has a PS4 connected by wire to his router. All other (three or four) clients are connected wirelessly (one through an extender). Whenever he starts playing online multiplayer, all wireless clients get disconnected within 30 seconds.

In attempt to correct this, I tried ridding them of the dinky ISP-provided modem/router combo. I replaced their modem with the same one I use (ActionTec I think) and let them have an old wireless-N Netgear router I had. Set everything up, and boom, same result. I'm at a loss as to how PS4 traffic could break the router, but that's the only reasonable conclusion I could come to.

Any idea what could cause this behavior? My next guess is to set the PS4 as a DMZ in case it's a firewall issue, but even if that fixes it, I wouldn't know why.

Comment: Could you clarify this question?  When you say disconnected, do you mean that the wireless clients get disconnected from the wireless? Are still connected wirelessly but can no longer access anything on the local network? Can still access devices on the local network, but can't access the internet? You need to better define the problem before someone could be able to provide an actual answer.

Comment: Actually disconnected from the LAN. For the first 10 seconds, ping latency goes up to 1 second. Then the router drops them from the client table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try use a longer network cable to connect PS4 and the router. Then move them apart as far as possible.
2. Disable wifi in PS4 if possible?!

Interference is the only cause I can think of.

Comment: Interesting thought. Will try that soon.